# Можно ли использовать классы из другого модуля?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

У меня есть java проект, где есть несколько модулей(A и B) для передачи информации между ними я использую  брокер сообщений RabbitMQ, так получается, что в модуле B мне нужен класс который находится в модуле А. Я знаю, что с помощью Maven можно получить этот класс, но является это хорошей идеей? Если еще более точнее, то я передаю через брокер распарешный класс и в модуле B мне нужно опять получить объект, но он находится в модуле A. Или я должен создать новый?

Comment: Если у вас есть `"распарешный класс"`, то создать из него объект не составляет особого труда.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если ваш проект модульный, то, как по мне, самое правильное решение - выносить все дто в отдельный модуль, который будет импортироваться в остальные модули. таким образом, вы решите проблему зависимостей между модулями в целом и проблему циклических зависимостей модулей в частности. кроме того, вам не нужно будет дублировать классы и думать о том, что при добавлении поля в класс одного модуля нужно не забыть добавить аналогичное поле в такой же класс другого модуля. Думаю, что это будет оптимальным и самым простым решением вашей проблемы. удачи

Comment: я в принципе так думал, спасибо за ответ